# Finding Antilog in javascript and solving polynomial equation of n degree in javascript

Tags: math, javascript, polynomial-math

Can anybody tell me how to solve polynomial equation of n degrees in JavaScript?  Also how can I find antilogs in JavaScript?  Is there any function by which I can find the antilog of any number?

Comment: eh? Why the change of heart. The now accepted answer is wrong...

Comment: i posted one question nobody is giving me answer saying you have less accepted rate. i am very much frustrated with this community seems like this place is only for those who have brilliant skills in computer science not the person like me who are no-voice in this field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Math.pow(x,y);// x^y
```

Thats for polynomials

```
Math.log(x);
```

Thats for logs.

<strike>Math.pow(10,x);
Thats for antilog</strike>

You have to come up with some function to solve antilog

Comment: Since `Math.log` finds log with base e (Euler's Constant), the reverse can be found with `Math.exp`

Answer (score 3):

To find the antilog(x) you just raise your base (usually 10) to the power of x.  In JavaScript:

```
Math.pow(10, x); // 10^x
```

If you have another base, just put it in place of 10 in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const e = Math.exp(1)

function antilog(n, base = e) {
  if (base === e) return Math.exp(n)

  return Math.pow(base, n)
}
```

`Math.log()` uses base `e`. `Math.exp(1)` gives you the value of `e`.

This `antilog` function is nice because it has the opposite API of the following `log` function:

```js
function log(n, base = e) {
  if (base === e) return Math.log(n)

  return Math.log(n) / Math.log(base)
}
```

I like these functions because they lead to cleaner code:

```js
const a = log(someNumber)
const b = antilog(someNumber)
```

and when you want to work with a different base, no need to write math expressions:

```js
const a = log(someNumber, 10)
const b = antilog(someNumber, 10)
```

Compare that to arbitrarily having to, or not having to, write:

```js
const a = Math.log(someNumber)
const b = Math.exp(someNumber)
```

or

```js
const a = Math.log(someNumber) / Math.log(10)
const b = Math.pow(10, someNumber)
```

`log` and `antilog` are more readable, easier.

Comment: I suggest `Math.exp(n)` instead of `Math.pow(Math.exp(1), n)`: it's simpler, faster, and more accurate.

Comment: @MarkDickinson It doesn't work when wanting other bases. I updated my answer. The end usage is cleaner than with the `Math` functions. Writing `symlog` and `antisymlog` functions has even more benefit from this approach, otherwise the math expressions will become even more unreadable. `Math.*` functions are more complicated.